# ElseIf Statement Not Evaluating All Conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

***Cross posted on Mr.Excel Messageboards at [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/if-statement-stopping-after-first-true-value.1154892/#post-5598602).  No answers have been given yet, so cross posting here***

I have a User Form where a user can select multiple values where they want to enter a person's name onto the spreadsheet. The macro should be looping through all 4 potential selections and placing the name in the "D" Column based upon conditions set in columns "O" and "P". However, my loop is stopping after it enters the first person's name. I believe it's because once the first "True" statement is found, it stops evaluating the rest of the statement. I've searched on the internet, but I'm having trouble figuring out a better way to complete this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
Private Sub btnAddToScoreSheet_Click()

Dim RelayNumber1 As Long, RelayNumber2, RelayNumber3, RelayNumber4
Dim PostNumber1 As Long, PostNumber2, PostNumber3, PostNumber4
Dim SquadNumber1 As Long, SquadNumber2, SquadNumber3, SquadNumber4
Dim PlayerName As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

SquadNumber1 = Me.txtSquad1.Value
SquadNumber2 = Me.txtSquad2.Value
SquadNumber3 = Me.txtSquad3.Value
SquadNumber4 = Me.txtSquad4.Value

RelayNumber1 = Me.txtRelay1.Value
RelayNumber2 = Me.txtRelay2.Value
RelayNumber3 = Me.txtRelay3.Value
RelayNumber4 = Me.txtRelay4.Value

PostNumber1 = Me.txtPost1.Value
PostNumber2 = Me.txtPost2.Value
PostNumber3 = Me.txtPost3.Value
PostNumber4 = Me.txtPost4.Value

PlayerName = Me.txtPlayerName.Value


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Score Sheet")
LastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For r = 2 To LastRow

If WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber1 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber1 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad1.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost1.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay1.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber2 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber2 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad2.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost2.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay2.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber3 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber3 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad3.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost3.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay3.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber4 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber4 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad4.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost4.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay4.Value = ""
    
     End If

Next r
 

MsgBox "Added all squads to sheet"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
Unload Me

End Sub
```

[image: Spreadsheet Sample]

[image: UserFormExample]

Comment: What's in ColA?  What is the value of `LastRow ` ?

Comment: Column "A" is primarily an unused Column.  It has some numbers in sporadic rows that help identify which Squad and Post a player is assigned to.  LastRow is = 251.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're declaring most of your variables as variant instead of Long. Also I believe you should use an array instead of several squadNumber variables

Comment: First thing, you have only declared the first of your variables (eg SquadNumber1 as a Long, the rest are Variants by default). I think VBA text boxes return values as Strings. SquadNumber1 is declared as a Long, so VBA does the conversion for you. With the others, SquadNumber2 is likely a String = “4”. So in your ElseIf statements you are testing whether a number 4 = a string “4”, which it probably doesn’t. Declare all you variables as Long individually and see what happens?

Comment: The Elseif is doing what it is supposed to do.  Only consider if the previous statement or statements are not true.  If you want all scenarios to be evaluated, you can create four `IF` statements within the loop.  There are other ways to make this work, but this will ensure all are considered.  When testing, you can use `F8` to step through a couple of iterations and watch the values and the types in your locals window to see if you are getting what you expected.

Comment: Fernando and London were absolutely correct!  The text boxes return as Strings, so what I had to do is declare all the variables individually as Strings and it worked exactly as intended.  Thank you all for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The commenters on this question were incredibly helpful, please see their comments for the reason this wasn't working.  The corrected code is:

```
Private Sub btnAddToScoreSheet_Click()

Dim RelayNumber1 As String
Dim RelayNumber2 As String
Dim RelayNumber3 As String
Dim RelayNumber4 As String
Dim PostNumber1 As String
Dim PostNumber2 As String
Dim PostNumber3 As String
Dim PostNumber4 As String
Dim SquadNumber1 As String
Dim SquadNumber2 As String
Dim SquadNumber3 As String
Dim SquadNumber4 As String
Dim PlayerName As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

SquadNumber1 = Me.txtSquad1.Value
SquadNumber2 = Me.txtSquad2.Value
SquadNumber3 = Me.txtSquad3.Value
SquadNumber4 = Me.txtSquad4.Value

RelayNumber1 = Me.txtRelay1.Value
RelayNumber2 = Me.txtRelay2.Value
RelayNumber3 = Me.txtRelay3.Value
RelayNumber4 = Me.txtRelay4.Value

PostNumber1 = Me.txtPost1.Value
PostNumber2 = Me.txtPost2.Value
PostNumber3 = Me.txtPost3.Value
PostNumber4 = Me.txtPost4.Value

PlayerName = Me.txtPlayerName.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Score Sheet")
LastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For r = 2 To LastRow
If WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber1 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber1 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad1.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost1.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay1.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber2 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber2 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad2.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost2.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay2.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber3 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber3 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad3.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost3.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay3.Value = ""
ElseIf WS.Cells(r, 15) = SquadNumber4 And WS.Cells(r, 16) = PostNumber4 Then
    WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = PlayerName
    Me.txtSquad4.Value = ""
    Me.txtPost4.Value = ""
    Me.txtRelay4.Value = ""
    
     End If

Next r
 

MsgBox "Added all squads to sheet"

 
Unload Me

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might be better off declaring your variables as Long. They really are numbers: it is only a quirk of the text box that you get strings. Let VBA convert the strings to Long or do it explicitly (my preference). But in the end, if the code does what you need ...